# show modal view in parserDidEndDocument

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller, nsxmlparser, modalviewcontroller

I founded that the problem is the place where I'm calling the showNextView. I have another interface webService where i communicate with server and parse xml. When the parsing is finished with method parserDidEndDocument I'm calling the delegate method where is changed the view and show modal view. But when i call all that methods it will return to endDocument and xmlParseChunk and so on. It looks like the parserDidEndDocument is not realy the last method and somehow it mess with navigationcontroler. When i call the method for showig nextView with button it works.

The code which is working on button. In delegate method called from parserDidEndDocument is not working correct.

```
-(void)showNextView
{
    UIViewController *nextView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vcTrabantInfo"];
    [[nextView navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];

    UIViewController *picker = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [picker setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];

    [[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];    
}
```

Comment: As usualy the problem was between keyboard and seat. The problem was that my modal views haven't been dismissed before i call another modal view :). So keep in mind that all is done in viewDidDisappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usualy the problem was between keyboard and seat. The problem was that my modal views haven't been dismissed before i call another modal view :). So keep in mind that all is done in viewDidDisappear.